# Loading ZX Spectrum tape audio in a post-cassette world

Tags: zx-spectrum, cassette-tape, audio

My ZX Spectrum 48k seems very resistant to working with audio input. I no longer have any cassette players, so am relying on audio files from digital players. I have been able to save and verify a tiny BASIC program to a digital recorder, but getting the right volume to save files from playtzx or OTLA is eluding me.

Things I've tried:

- [TeeZiX - TZX/TAP player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.rift.tzxdroid&hl=en) on my phone
- Many different audio cables, mono, stereo and TRRS
- Edirol R-1 digital recorder/player (this is the one I got the save and verify to work on, and it has good input/output volume control)
- a Sandisk Sansa player running Rockbox
- an 800 Hz square wave tone at 0 dB to see if I could trigger the record level and make the screen border flicker. (summary: nope)
- Audio files from tape2wav/[PlayTZX](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/utilities.html) and [otla](https://code.google.com/archive/p/otla/) (via wine).

What else should I try?

Comment: You are using the EAR input on your Spectrum, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, but thanks for asking. The Sinclair's EAR ↔ EAR and MIC ↔ MIC (but never both at the same time) is different from RX ↔ TX I typically do with null modems.

Comment: Try using [DivIDE](http://www.divide.cz/files/divIDE_manual_en.pdf) device -- while not a sound player, it effectively emulates tape loading calls and makes loading faaast.

Comment: But it's not an audio solution, @lvd — and that's what I was asking about. I have a Retroleum [SMART card](http://www.retroleum.co.uk/smart-card-for-zx-spectrum/ "SMART card") that does fast loading of snapshots

Comment: Newest developments: TZX Duino and Arduitape (Google for them) are Arduino-based devices that can play TZX files as audio into the Spectrum. They are kind of new in summer 2017.

Comment: Every single Walgreens I go to still has cassette tapes. Not VHS tapes for some reason. But plenty of cassette tapes. So, this is not really a "Post-Cassette world" yet.

Comment: Not every country has Walgreens, @LateralTerminal. I can't think of a single high-street shop that would carry them here. While I have a couple of cassette units and a few decade-old unopened C60s, they're not anything most users would readily interact with — or want to, given the easy availability of better audio in phones and computers

Comment: Are we really in a "post-cassette world"?  Cassette decks and blank cassettes remain available on the market, and indeed are enjoying a resurgence.

Comment: Yes, @JimMacKenzie, indeed we are. You can futz with tapes and recorders all you want, but the cheapest smartphone or MP3 player outperforms them all.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**If (and only if) your audio player is battery powered**, and your Spectrum is the 48K or 128K toastrack model, try the following procedure, intended to boost the volume of your wave signal, as seen by the Spectrum EAR circuitry:

- Get one of these audio cables. They are very common. And yes, they are stereo.

[image]

Why do we need it to be stereo? The trick is that both channels from the 3.5'' stereo plug will make contact inside the Spectrum jack this way:

[image]

So when you use it to load from a digital audio player, that will normally output the same level in both channels, you won't hear (or load) anything.

Then what? Just invert one of the channels so the voltage level of one channel, reffered to the other channel, will appear to be double the value of any of both channel reffered to ground (which won't be connected at all in our setup)

If the TAP/TZX conversion program allows this inversion, use it. If not, you can use an editor program like Audacity to perform the inversion. Here is how:

First, load your generated WAV into Audacity. The generated WAV should be stereo, but if not, it doesn't matter. We can clone one channel to the other one to make it stereo.

[image]

Use the magnifier tool inside the wave window to amgnify it to the point you can clearly see both waves, that initially will look the same.

[image]

Now click on the wav name tab and select "Split stereo track"

[image]

Now we have the left and right channels in different tracks, so we can manipulate each one independently.

Change to the select tool (above the magnifier tool) and click the second track (the one below the other) as near as possible to the beginning of it. Press Home to bring the selection mark to the very beginning of the track. From the menu, select Edit -> Select -> Cursor to Track End so the whole track is selected.

[image]

With that selection active, select Effect -> Invert

[image]

Now we have two independent tracks, one of them with an inverted version of the sound of the other one.

[image]

Now select both tracks: press Shift and click on both tracks (the region where the properties of each track are displayed). Then, click on the name of any of them and select "Make stereo track"

[image]

The final result should be a stereo track with one channel inverted.

[image]

Save this wave as PCM stereo track by choosing File -> Export

[image]

And then, WAV

[image]

Copy it to your digital audio player and use the stereo cable as described to play the resulting sound. Don't be surprised if you need to lower the volume in order to get it loaded.

For example, in order to load this Bruce Lee example with a Samsung Onyx, I had to do it using the MIC input on the Spectrum, as the EAR input was too loud to be usable.

[image]

Comment: Somewhat to my surprise, that worked rather well. Thank you! I'll add a `sox` script to this page to do the same as your very well explained Audacity method.

Comment: What a fantastic answer. Both in terms of the actual answer, and in terms of the effort you made to present and explain the answer. Awesome work!

Comment: Why "IF YOUR AUDIO PLAYER IS BATTERY POWERED ONLY"???
Thanks

Comment: If the audio player and the computer share a common ground — as they would if they were mains powered — there would no longer be the differential voltage range of +0 → +2×Vₛ.

Comment: What is the purpose of all this? To effectively double the volume without adding distortion? In other words, why would a tape player work while an audio player wouldn't?

Comment: Yes, this doubles the volume. Audio players work (as long as they're not mains-connected), but they tend to have a much lower signal level than the old cassette players.

Comment: An AC-powered audio player ought to be OK as long as its power supply is isolated, not grounded. If in doubt, use a multimeter to check there is no continuity between the sleeve of a stereo cable plugged into the audio player and the ring of a stereo cable plugged into the Spectrum. If there is, you would be shorting out one output of the audio player which might damage it.

Comment: @traal - "why would a tape player work while an audio player wouldn't?" -- because modern standalone battery-powered audio player devices are subject to [regulations](http://www.who.int/pbd/deafness/Monograph_on_situation_analysis_and_background_for_standards_for_safe_listening_systems.pdf) that require them to limit output to 100dbA and to issue a warning when volume is set to greater than 85dbA when coupled with modern high-sensitivity earphones.  This effectively requires them to produce at most a few hundred mV of output level, which is lower than traditional levels, because ...

Comment: ... modern earphones are a lot more sensitive than the ones the standards were originally designed for.  These regulations only apply to portable battery-powered devices intended for personal music playing, so your traditional desktop tape player or stereo system isn't covered by them, therefore even modern tape players still produce the traditional output levels.  The spectrum requires at least 1.2V to recognise an input signal.

Comment: (I seem to be wrong about the 1.2V requirement, because you wouldn't get that with the approach described; I don't know what voltage the spectrum does require to recognise a signal.  I have a suspicion it's 0.6V, but am just guessing now...)

Comment: Why not using a mono cable and playing back the sound on the left channel only with higher volume?

Comment: @MartinRosenau - because the maximum volume of most modern audio player devices is too low for the Spectrum's input circuit.

Comment: Awesome answer! I am going to test it on another vintage computer (VTech Laser 500) which has a similar tape interface. If that works, I will add a specific option to a program-to-wav utility that I'm writing. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

I've confirmed that mcleod_ideafix's method is reliable for regular tape images. Here is a shell script to do (effectively) the same thing:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wav2differential.sh - convert mono game tape audio to 2× stereo
# usage:   wav2differential.sh infile.wav
#          (creates  infile-differential.wav)
# scruss - 2016-06-07
# method by ‘mcleod_ideafix’; many thanks / greetz
#   — https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/774/439

base="${1%.wav}"
sox -q --norm=-3 "$1" -b 16 "${base}-n.wav"
sox -q  "${base}-n.wav" "${base}-ni.wav" vol -1.0
sox -q  --norm=-0.1 -M -c 1 "${base}-n.wav" -c 1 "${base}-ni.wav" "${base}-differential.wav"
rm -f  "${base}-n.wav" "${base}-ni.wav"
```

Ultimately I'd like to encode these as MP3s, tag them properly, and add loading screens as cover art. But that can come later.

**What this script does** — for people who might want to port it to systems without the Bash shell. Assume the script has been called with an argument *game.wav*, a mono audio file of the game loader:

1. set the variable *base* to the value *game*; that is, the base name of the file argument, stripped of its file extension. I'll assume that the variable has been substituted from here on
2. create a temporary mono audio file *game-n.wav* from *game.wav* with the volume set to -3 dB (`--norm=-3`) with 16-bit samples (`-b 16`)
3. create a temporary mono audio file *game-ni.wav* from *game-n.wav* with the samples inverted (`vol -1.0`)
4. merge (`-M`) the two mono temporary files *game-n.wav* and *game-ni.wav* into a stereo output file *game-differential.wav*, correcting the peak volume to be -0.1 dB, or just below clipping (`--norm=-0.1`)
5. remove the temporary files *game-n.wav* and *game-ni.wav*

The `-q` sox option I used throughout is just to make sox quiet: it tends to create lots of text output that you don't really need.

Comment: For MP3, encode them as stereo (**not joint stereo**) and 128 kbps or more.

Comment: Dear @scruss can you give me more details (if and) how can I use this script in Windows? (I have SOX installed of course). Thanx

Comment: Sorry, @PanosPlat, I don't know anything about Windows scripting, but I'll add something to my answer so you can see what it does to port it

Comment: Thank you very much @scruss! If I achieve anything, I ll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to start using ZX Tape Player application:

- [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tekdeq.zxtapeplayer) version
- [iOS](https://testflight.apple.com/join/SaoGn65t) version, can be installed using TestFight
- The [Source Code](https://github.com/semack/zx_tape_player) of the app, welcome to contribution! ;)

Enjoy! ;)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Cool idea. It might be fair to disclose your involvement.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems getting my PC to work with OTLA on my 48+ model. What I did was play the .wav file through Video Lan Player (VLC) on full blast (125%) and it worked!

I used a stereo to split channel lead using phono to jack adaptors (basically green line in to red/white phono audio connections). I'm sure there's an easier way but this is the way that worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Retro SE! Why did you decide to physically split the cable? Couldn't you simply mute one channel in VLC to achieve the same effect?

Comment: By the way, 125% isn't full, so you might get some distortion (floating point rounding errors, clipping) if you do that. Probably nothing that a system / emulated system wouldn't be able to deal with, but still...

Answer (score -3):

You don't have to do all this to load games into ZX Spectrum! The main thing is that your audio player has **low output signal**, so it just can't do the job.

You must play audio files on PC, but only rear speaker output, because you can burn front headphone output! Also, any amplifier is OK.

**Audio files must be in WAV format.** Absolutely no tuning and recompressing needed.

Don't use mp3 format to save space, because it can never be perfect as WAV.

Everything is explained in my **Youtube video**:

https://youtu.be/iD1_HRhXIyc

[image: ZX Spectrum loading games]

Comment: PC rear speaker output — where's that on my laptop? Consider it likely that not everyone has the same hardware (or software) as you. Cassettes (and desktop PCs, up to a point) were commodity items, and now they're not. You should probably also say that this is your video. It doesn't say much more than the text you put in your post.

Comment: The format of the files - WAV, MP3, MIDI, etc - is irrelevant.  The output required is analogue.  To agree with Scruss, none of my PCs have more than out audio output port, so suggesting one is better than another is irrelevant.

Comment: Scruss, PC rear means the back of the PC. *[trimmed]* Also, I specified in video that you can't use laptop. *[trimmed]* My name is at the end of video, not hidden. Chenmunka, Play WAV and you got analogue, relevant enough. If you have one output, it's amplified. *[trimmed]*

Comment: I asked this question. I think I pretty much know what answers are helpful or not. As the site says: *Be nice, and check out our [Code of Conduct](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/conduct).*

Comment: @Sasha381 Your answer isn't very clear, and your comment come sacross as quite abrasive. Plus, we do have a disclosure requirement when you're linking to your own resources; you have to say _in the answer_ that it's yours, not just _in the video_. (And laptops don't have a PC rear, but _can_ be used for this purpose.)

Comment: I just wanted to help, but I got unwelcome comments and thumbs down, so I reacted properly. Anyway, I hope my answer will help someone else.